# OrientDB missing index

Tags: orientdb

I have a problema with a index. 
First the index stop to work. When I try to regenerate from the WebStudio it throw an error, so I try to drop and recreate it. 
After drop the index, it's no longer exist in the schema tab but when I try to create it again it throw:

com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexException: Cannot create the index 'Pais.nombre'
 DB name="tantalo"
 --> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: File Pais.nombre.sbt has already been added to the storage
 DB name="tantalo"

I have removed the file "Pais.nombre.sbt" from the database folder but it still throwing the error and the database seems to not detect the problem.
All of this in 3.0.9 version.
What can I do?

Comment: I have droped the vertex class and recreate it but the problema remains

Comment: Well. I have made a mistake with the database. When I remove the sbt file I chosse it in the incorrect db vesion (I have installed 2.2.29, 3.0.7, 3.0.8 and 3.0.9). 
Now I have removed the file in the correct directory and the DB let me create the index. 
But this fix is a workaround. The DB issue remains.

Comment: Hi Marcelo D. Ré, have you tried to use check database? And then repair?